# Setting up keystore programmatically before getting default SSL context

Tags: java, security, java-security, java-security-manager

I am in the impression that once I set system properties when I get SSLContext.getDefault() should return me SSLContext with those set properties. In the following case should be with specified keyStore. Unfortunately that's not what is happening. It falls back JVM's default keystore. Am I missing something ?

```
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "/valida-location/keyStore.jks");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","changeit");
            System.setProperty("sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation", "true");

            answer = SSLContext.getDefault();
```

Comment: What do you get in the logs when you run with `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl'`? Does it show that it reads `/keyStore.jks`?

Comment: `keyStore is : 
keyStore type is : jks
keyStore provider is : 
init keystore 
init keymanager of type SunX509
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true` This is what I get in logs @KarolDowbecki

Comment: Can you re-run with `-D` properties instead of `System.setProperty()`? I'm trying to confirm if your keystore location and password is correct.

Comment: (1) is this code executed before any other reference to any SSL-related classes by any code in your JVM processs? (It must be.) (2) Is `/keyStore.jks` really in your system's root directory (or on Windows the drive's)?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 please see my answer. Although I tried putting those two properties in my constructor, that too was too late. So, in the end, put that in a static block. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

I think by the time `answer = SSLContext.getDefault();` was about to execute, SSLContext related classed were already loaded. I solved it by putting

`System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "/valida-location/keyStore.jks");
 System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","changeit");`
 in static block of my class. That way, there properties were set at the time of class loading. Thanks to @dave_thompson_085 for hint.